# Canonical URL link tag is not working for LinkedIn

Tags: html, linkedin-api, meta-tags

LinkedIn Post inspector:
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fgourav.io%2Fblog%2Fgit-cheatsheet

in page HTML Head, canonical url is `<link rel="canonical" href="https://gourav.io/blog/git-cheatsheet">`

[image]

However, On LinkedIn canonical URL is showing `https://gourav.io`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's working now, here are the metatags
[image]